# Changing skin for ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Am I able to change skin?
I'm creating angular app, that has light and dark theme.
I have prepared two ckeditor skins. But even if I destroy ck instance, next instance has previuos skin - not current.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor4 skins are applied to instance creation, so recreating instance is a good way to dynamically update editor skin. You should be able to pass configuration option [config.skin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-skin) when replacing DOM element with an editor to indicate its skin e.g:

```js
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
  skin: 'moono'
} );
```

Note that custom skin should be placed in `skins` folder or you should pass additional information about location, e.g.

```js
config.skin = 'myskin,/customstuff/myskin/';
```

If you still struggle with setting custom skin, please share your current implementation.

Comment: Do we need that skin path exist locally in our project ?