# How to change theme/skin on CKEditor from light to dark?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor for my site, I'm trying to turn all elements from light to become a dark mode.

[image]

---

## I have

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>



<textarea name="description" rows="100" cols="80" id="description">
......TEXTS......
</textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
CKEDITOR.config.height = 500;
</script>
```

---

## I've tried

Download the zip, and move it into my project at `/js`.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'description', {
    skin: 'moonocolor,/js/ckeditor/skins/moono-dark/skin.js',
    height : 500
} );
```

This line

> skin: 'moonocolor,/js/ckeditor/skins/moono-dark/skin.js',

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What version are you using? For version 5, its already in the documentation, you can see it [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/theme-customization.html)

Comment: I'm on 4.8.0, but I can upgrade.

Comment: Can you update the answer showing how to update it dark mode ckEditor ?

Comment: @cyber8200 you can build your editor with this theme https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/moono-dark

Comment: I've tried to configure, and it is not working.

Comment: I might be being stupid, but do you not put skins in the `<CKEditor folder>/skins/` folder (call the new folder `moonocolor`. Then just add `skin: moonocolor` (or add `config.skin = 'moonocolor'`) and it wires it all up automatically?

Comment: This is the documentation for version 4 - looks like I am right? https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_skins.html#installing-skins-manually

Comment: Yes. I’m using the version 4.

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085884/changing-skin-for-ckeditor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder
Choose Standard preset, then choose the skin Moono Dark, then click Download button at the end.
Unzip the file in `/js/` folder and just use:

```
<script src="/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea name="description" rows="100" cols="80" id="description">
</textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
</script>
```

No need to use `skin` config option since Moono Dark is the only skin in your setup.

EDIT: If you want black background with white text, add this line before the `replace` command:

```
CKEDITOR.addCss('.cke_editable { background-color: black; color: white }');
```

or edit `contents.css` in ckeditor directory and change CSS of `body` tag (but this file is replaced if you update ckeditor, so be careful)

or create a new file `myfile.css` in ckeditor directory with your CSS modifications of `body` tag or `.cke_editable` class and load it in your config file with:

```
config.contentsCss = [CKEDITOR.getUrl('contents.css'), CKEDITOR.getUrl('myfile.css')];
```

EDIT2: To change the border color you have to modify your web page CSS, not ckeditor, like this:

```
.cke_chrome {
    border: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

For the bottom bar, I only know how to completely remove it, but you can't resize ckeditor after you do that. Add these lines to your config file:

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
config.resize_enabled = false;
```

Comment: I did that, it seems working now, but my background is still white, and my text is black, I want my background to be black and texts to be white, do you know a CSS on how to do that. I see this now. https://i.imgur.com/1a9gSa3.png

Comment: I have edited my answer for black background and white text.

Comment: What about the button bar, and border color (still white) ?  https://i.imgur.com/WViALwu.png

Comment: I like your suggestion to link to external .css, I will do that instead. Please help me with the border and the bottom part.

Comment: Let me check. Thank-you so much.

Comment: @Wizad :  As soon as I started to make it black, I can not access the content inside it anymore. I'm not sure. Why ? Can you please help ? I asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/61409284/4480164

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Wizard's accepted answer, to format the bottom bar you need to modify your web page CSS, not CKEditor, like this

```
.cke_bottom {
    background-image: none !important;
    background: #333 !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #333 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.cke_path_item {
    color: #fff !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

a.cke_path_item:hover {
    background: #666 !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```