# Can't access text from CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have this text area

[image]

## HTML

```
<textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
```

## JS

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = [CKEDITOR.getUrl('contents.css'), 
CKEDITOR.getUrl('/js/ckeditor/skins/moono-dark/styles.css')];
```

I did this

```
$('textarea[name="description"]').keyup(function() {
    console.log($('textarea[name="description"]').val());
});
```

I see nothing on my console.

Can someone show me how to debug this further?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_savedata.html) you need something like `var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();` (also, your calling `.replace` probably means the textarea no longer exists)

Comment: ok let me try now

Comment: Yep, it works now; thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive events and access the updated content of the textarea  you must use the CKEDITOR object like this :

```
CKEDITOR.instances.description.on('change', function() { 
    console.log(CKEDITOR.instances.description.getData());
});
```